# Graphic implementation of firefly algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, sdl

I am looking for little help with graphic implementation of firefly algorithm. I am working with [this code](https://github.com/firefly-cpp/Firefly-algorithm--FFA-/blob/master/Firefly.cpp) in DevC++ and I want to use SDL library. But I don't know which values I should take to make graphic implementation. I am interested with something like [that](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.1409.pdf) (page 10).
Anyone have an idea how to do it? Of course I don't want solution - only hints and/or tutorials.

Comment: have you an idea of the data you wish to represent graphically? Something like a sample output, and a sample of how you want it to look?  If you can provide both of those, it would help in being able to advise on how to achieve it.

Comment: I want to show all iteration step-by-step; I mean how all fireflies try to make a group. My goal is make something like this program from MathLab (but in C++):
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29693-firefly-algorithm/content/firefly_simple.m

Comment: do you want to do it in 2d or 3d?

Comment: you could utilise a set of particles as the fireflies and derive the particle life, colour, brightness etc, from their computed values in the algorithm,  what becomes tricky is making it all happen in human time, my suggestion would be pre-compute it, saving each step into a data structure in memory, then replay the datastructure at human speeds for a 2d or 3d visual representation, otherwise you may blink and miss them moving:)

Comment: This problem piques my curiosity let me know if there's anything I can do to help (maybe a simple OpenGL framework to handle the particles etc)

Comment: I would prefer 3d, but 2d is good for a start. Do you think I should stay with DevC++ or instal MS Visual C++?

Comment: either or is fine, for portability I use DevC++ on my usb drive, but for my main machines I have msvs c++ installed, that way you get the best of both:)

Comment: Ok :) So I try write some code and I will send post about my progress. Thank you for help and I am sure I will write to you many times :)

Comment: no problem:) this actually sounds quite interesting, glad to help:)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you might want to look this repository : it is a solution to solve verbal arithmetic problems using JavaFX. [Firefly algorithm + GUI. GitHub](https://github.com/yogonza524/fireflyFx)

About the repository:

- Source code and the latest release for solve Verbal-arithmetics problems

For example, an unit test

```
import com.core.luciernaga.Programa;
import com.core.luciernaga.Luciernaga;
import com.core.luciernaga.Util;

 @Test
 public void first(){
     Programa p = new Programa();
     p.setOperacion("+");
     Util.setEnableInfo(true); //to show the results
     p.setPalabra1("MONEY".toCharArray());
     p.setPalabra2("MORE".toCharArray());
     p.setPalabra3("SEND".toCharArray());

     int n = 0;
     int totalIterations = 30;
     while(p.getLuciernagaSolucion() == null && n < totalIterations){
         p.programa();
         n++;
     }
     if (p.getLuciernagaSolucion() != null) {
         Util.info("Problem solved!");
         p.mostrarSolución();
     }
 }
```